# Kotlin wrap sequential IO calls as a Sequence

Tags: kotlin, io, sequence, kotlin-coroutines

I need to process all of the results from a paged API endpoint. I'd like to present all of the results as a sequence.

I've come up with the following (slightly psuedo-coded):

```
suspend fun getAllRowsFromAPI(client: Client): Sequence<Row> {
    var currentRequest: Request? = client.requestForNextPage()
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         sequence {
            while(currentRequest != null) {
                var rowsInPage = runBlocking { client.makeRequest(currentRequest) }
                currentRequest = client.requestForNextPage()
                yieldAll(rowsInPage)
            }
        }
     }
}
```

This functions but I'm not sure about a couple of things:

1. Is the API request happening inside `runBlocking` still happening with the IO dispatcher?
2. Is there a way to refactor the code to launch the next request before yielding the current results, then awaiting on it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**: The API-request will still run on the IO-dispatcher, but it will block the thread it's running on. This means that no other tasks can be scheduled on that thread while waiting for the request to finish. There's not really any reason to use `runBlocking` in production-code at all, because:

1. If `makeRequest` is already a blocking call, then `runBlocking` will do practically nothing.
2. If `makeRequest` was a suspending call, then `runBlocking` would make the code less efficient. It wouldn't yield the thread back to the pool while waiting for the request to finish.

Whether `makeRequest` is a blocking or non-blocking call depends on the client you're using. Here's a non-blocking http-client I can recommend: https://ktor.io/clients/

**Question 2**: I would use a `Flow` for this purpose. You can think of it as a suspendable variant of `Sequence`. Flows are *cold*, which means that it won't run before the consumer asks for its contents (in contrary to being *hot*, which means the producer will push new values no matter if the consumer wants it or not). A Kotlin `Flow` has an operator called `buffer` which you can use to make it request more pages before it has fully consumed the previous page.

The code could look quite similar to what you already have:

```
suspend fun getAllRowsFromAPI(client: Client): Flow<Row> = flow {
    var currentRequest: Request? = client.requestForNextPage()

    while(currentRequest != null) {
        val rowsInPage = client.makeRequest(currentRequest)
        emitAll(rowsInPage.asFlow())
        currentRequest = client.requestForNextPage()
    }
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
.buffer(capacity = 1)
```

The capacity of 1 means that will only make 1 more request while processing an earlier page. You could increase the buffer size to make more concurrent requests.
You should check out this talk from KotlinConf 2019 to learn more about flows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYcqn48SMT8

Answer (score 0):

Sequences are definitely not the thing you want to use in this case, because they are not designed to work in asynchronous environment. Perhaps you should take a look at flows and channels, but for your case the best and simplest choice is just a collection of deferred values, because you want to process all requests at once (flows and channels process them one-by-one, maybe with limited buffer size).

The following approach allows you to start all requests asynchronously (assuming that `makeRequest` is suspended function and supports asynchronous requests). When you'll need your results, you'll need to wait only for the slowest request to finish.

```
fun getClientRequests(client: Client): List<Request> {
    val requests = ArrayList<Request>()
    var currentRequest: Request? = client.requestForNextPage()
    while (currentRequest != null) {
        requests += currentRequest
        currentRequest = client.requestForNextPage()
    }
    return requests
}

// This function is not even suspended, so it finishes almost immediately
fun getAllRowsFromAPI(client: Client): List<Deferred<Page>> =
    getClientRequests(client).map {
        /* 
         * The better practice would be making getAllRowsFromApi an extension function
         * to CoroutineScope and calling receiver scope's async function.
         * GlobalScope is used here just for simplicity.
         */
        GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { client.makeRequest(it) }
    }

fun main() {
    val client = Client()
    val deferredPages = getAllRowsFromAPI(client) // This line executes fast
    // Here you can do whatever you want, all requests are processed in background
    Thread.sleep(999L)
    // Then, when we need results....
    val pages = runBlocking {
        deferredPages.map { it.await() }
    }
    println(pages)
    // In your case you also want to "unpack" pages and get rows, you can do it here:
    val rows = pages.flatMap { it.getRows() }
    println(rows)
}
```

Comment: Please don't recommend using `GlobalScope`. It will make you leak coroutines if it, for example, throws an exception. If you need to launch a coroutine from your function, then making it an extension function on `CoroutineScope` should be the default.

Comment: @marstran If the coroutine throws an exception, there's definitely no leak. Leaks happen when the initiator of the concurrent coroutine disappears but the coroutine keeps doing its work.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, but that is more likely to happen when you have multiple coroutines running in GlobalScope and one of them throws an exception.

Comment: @marstran That still doesn't describe a leak. It happens only when one coroutine launches more coroutines and is the only one that needs their results. If that coroutine aborts, then the other coroutines will continue in vain, creating a leak. Actually, the most common way for this to happen is when the top-level isn't even a coroutine but a GUI element that the user can navigate away from.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It was never my intention to describe what a leak _is_...

Comment: `It will make you leak coroutines if it, for example, throws an exception.` That sounds like an attempt. My point: when advising against `GlobalScope`, the argument should be substantial and not based on a blindly followed guideline.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Blindly followed guideline? Where do you get that from? It was a simple comment. I cannot describe the complete world every time I make a comment. That sentence was an attempt to keep it short and concise.

Comment: @marstran Short and concise shouldn't be incompatible with correct. A coroutine throwing an exception isn't an example of a leak.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And as I have explained, that is not what I meant either...

Answer (score 0):

I happened across `suspendingSequence` in Kotlin's `coroutines-examples`:

https://github.com/Kotlin/coroutines-examples/blob/090469080a974b962f5debfab901954a58a6e46a/examples/suspendingSequence/suspendingSequence.kt

This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I would be very happy to hear about the (dis)advantages of this approach vs. the other answers

Comment: That code is just an example of how you can use coroutines. The SuspendingSequence is called a Flow in the standard coroutines library. You should use that instead of rolling your own implementation.